# Regex for phrase that contains linebreak

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to find the following italic+bold text:

I am stuck I am stuck ***I am

stuck*** I am stuck I am stuck
I am stuck I am stuck ***I

am stuck*** I am stuck

What I am interested in is getting the occurrences of the text "I am stuck" only when it contains a linebreak.
I somehow thought I can go through a capturing group like this:

```
(this\s+is\s+cool)
```

and then return the match that contains a linebreak. Right now, all occurrences are selected and I cannot figure out what the best approach to solving this issue would be. Any hint in the right direction would be appreciated! [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Y1rrNN/2)

I am using C#.

Comment: Does it mean you need to extract those texts, or remove the line breaks?

Comment: I guess `(I\nam stuck|I am\nstuck)` might work..

Comment: I need to extract those words and basically get the INDEX of the starting character. The phrase can consist of 2 or more words.

Comment: Ok, I think that `\b(?:I\s*\n\s*am\s+stuck|I\s+am\s*\n\s*stuck)\b` will do.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes, works - I am just concerned about longer phrases with more words. Was wondering if there is a better way of doing this with regular expressions. But your solution is the one I would go for if there is no better way. I also do not know the phrase ahead of time and need to generate the regex during runtime.

Comment: You could also just collect all matches and check `Contains("\n")` in C# on all of them - might be simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you *have to* use a one regex approach, you might use a regex with two alternatives that will match one `I am stuck` with a newline in between `I` and `am` and the second in between `am` and `stuck`:

```
\b(?:I\s*\n\s*am\s+stuck|I\s+am\s*\n\s*stuck)\b
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%3F%3AI%5Cs*%5Cn%5Cs*am%5Cs%2Bstuck%7CI%5Cs%2Bam%5Cs*%5Cn%5Cs*stuck%29%5Cb&i=I%20am%20stuck%20I%20am%20stuck%20I%20am%0D%0Astuck%20I%20am%20stuck%20I%20am%20stuck%0D%0AI%20am%20stuck%20I%20am%20stuck%20I%0D%0Aam%20stuck%20I%20am%20stuck)

*However*, it is much easier to use `I\s+am\s+stuck` regex (with or without word boundaries, as per your needs), but filter out those matches that have no line breaks inside:

```
var ms = Regex.Matches(s, @"I\s+am\s+stuck")
     .Cast<Match>()
     .Where(m => m.Value.Contains("\n"));
```

Comment: This is nice because it doesn't involve a complicated regex.

Comment: I like this one too! Was focusing too much on regex when I could go ahead with regex + linq! Perfect!

Comment: I updated the answer to put the right accent on which solution is a preferred one.

Comment: Many times I find that a simple Regex plus a bit of code is a much better solution than a complicated Regex